# Can install4j ignore previously installations on reinstall/upgrade for default directory?

Tags: install4j

How can I get my install4j installer to always suggest the default installation and not try to use the previous installation directory.

I added my directory to the media and checked **Suggest Application directory** on the **Installation Location** screen but I'm still getting undesirable behavior.

Wanted behavior:

- user installed  C:\Program Files\My App 1.0.0\
- use runs installer for 2.0 and it prompts with C:\Program Files\My App 2.0.0\

Current behavior:

- user installed  C:\Program Files\My App 1.0.0\
- use runs installer for 2.0 and it prompts with C:\Program Files\My App **1.0.0**\

Thanks for the help

Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Installer->Update Options, deselect the check box "Detect previous installation directory".